# HTML5 Load smaller image in canvas and save actual size image

Tags: php, javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating a image editing tool using HTML 5 Canvas & Java script. I am loading large image to canvas by scaling an image to fit the canvas, apply some filters, and save back image to disk.

The problem is when I save a canvas to image it will store image with canvas size. What I want is image will be stored to its actual dimensions with applied filters. The Same approach used by Flickr.

For Example

if the image is 1000px X 1000px and displayed in a 300px X 300px canvas, I am loading image to canvas as 300px X 300px. while saving I still want to save the image with 1000px X 1000px dimesnion. How to do that?

I am developing using php, HTML5 & Javascript.

I want to do everything on client side, before sending an image to server

Any Help?

looking for a proper solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

Just need to change canvas size by using css & tag attribute

CSS width & height adjust display area of canvas
 Tag width & height are actual image width & height

For example:

```
#canvas { width:500px; height:350px}
<canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="760"></canvas>
```

Above will display canvas with block of 500px x 350px. 
However when canvas saved to image it will saved with image size 1024x760

Comment: Hi, how are you making the image small on the canvas?

Comment: Ys, image scaled n canvas like flicker, and when save image, it produce similar original size image

Answer (score 1):

use this link. It is having full tutorial.

http://www.sitepoint.com/image-resizing-php/

in this image's dimension will change accordingly.

**UPDATE**

For client side

http://ericjuden.com/2009/07/jquery-image-resize/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.story-small img').each(function() {
    var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if(width > maxWidth){
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
        $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if(height > maxHeight){
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
        $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Not useful, required all this in client side, no php for image processing

Comment: You didn't understand the question. Pls read carefully, I want to save canvas data to image with original image dimension